# PHP loop over array keys and return value

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am trying to loop over the keys of an array and return the value when that key matches with a variable. But what I am doing just doesn't seem to make much sense.

```
public function check($variable)
{
    $result = 0;

    $amount = array(
        3 => 10,
        4 => 20,
        5 => 50
        );

    foreach ($amount as $a) {
        if ($a == $variable) {
            $result = $a[$amount];
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

At this point I am not even sure anymore if what I am doing is right :p

Anyone who could help me out?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your expected output. Can you please post that too

Comment: hmmm.... I'm betting it should be: $result = $a... but its unclear what you want....

Comment: You use of keys and values is very confusing: What is the input and matching output? Some examples would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function check($variable)
{
    $result = 0;

    $amount = array(
        3 => 10,
        4 => 20,
        5 => 50
    );

    if (isset($amount[$variable])) {
        $result = $amount[$variable];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function check($variable)
{
    $result = 0;

    $amount = array(
        3 => 10,
        4 => 20,
        5 => 50
        );

    foreach ($amount as $k=>$v) {
        if ($k == $variable) {
            $result = $v;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need so much logic.. I think you don't need a function for that too, but here it is:

```
var_dump(check(4));

function check($variable)
{
    $amount = array(
        3 => 10,
        4 => 20,
        5 => 50
    );

    return isset($amount[$variable]) ? $amount[$variable] : 0;
}
```

As I can see this is a method inside a class.. it would be better to see all the methods from that class

Comment: How can I do this without a function?

Comment: It's a bit too much to show I want to do this check as part of an other rather big function

Answer (score 0):

```
function check($variable)
{
    $result = 0;
    $amount = array(
        3 => 10,
        4 => 20,
        5 => 50
        );


    foreach ($amount as $a) {
        if ($a == $variable) {
            $result = $a;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Basically the line assigning $a to $result wasn't in order. That was all that needed fixing. It now either returns 0 or the $variable if it's in the list. Frankly You were very close to the right code...